# validate laravel unique another schemas postgresql

Tags: laravel, validation

[my schema screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjHXX.png)

i want to use "sma" schemas on validate unique

 
first i use this code:

```
$m= [
            'number.unique' => 'Number' . $request['number'] . ' already used',
        ];

Validator::make($request, [
         'number' => ['required', 'unique:sma.users'],
     ], $m)->validate();
```

then this error show on my laravel

**Database connection [sma] not configured.**

then i try remove "sma"

```
Validator::make($request, [
         'number' => ['required', 'unique:users'],
     ], $m)->validate();
```

then this error show on my laravel

**Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "users" does not exist LINE 1: select count(*) as aggregate from "users" where ... ^ (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "users" where "number" = 69875543)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try add your connection:

'number' => ['required', 'unique:pgsql.sma.users'],

because schema need connection..